Differential Equation based off an Experiment
This question comes as a modification from a rates of change and differential equations question. It is slightly adapted for an experiment which I conducted a few days ago.
The rate of change of concentration $C$ of hydrogen peroxide after $t$ seconds is given by:
$$\frac{dC}{dt}=\frac{-VC}{K+C}$$
Where $K=0.00275$ mol $L^{-1}$ and $V=0.0144$.
Is there a way to write $t$ in terms of $C$, given that the initial concentration is $0.06$?

What is $C(t)$ ?

If everything but $C$ is a constant, then the equation is separable and easy to integrate to get $t$ in dependence of $C$.

Since $V,K$ are constant, we have a separable ODE, or equivalently, we can rewrite it as $$\dfrac{dt}{dC}=\dfrac{K+C}{-VC}=\dfrac{-K}{VC}-\dfrac{1}{V},\quad C(0)=0.06$$
Integrating both sides with respect to $C$ gives $$t=\dfrac{-K}{V}\ln C-\dfrac{C}{V}+\text{constant}$$
Substituting the initial condition you can get the exact formula of $t$, which should be $$t=-\dfrac{1}{V}(K\ln C+C-K\ln 0.06-0.06)$$
